# How to change a color of PhpStorm path bar?

Tags: phpstorm

[image]

PhpStorm 2016.3 
Build #PS-163.7743.50, built on November 22,2016

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found!

Here is my settings, maybe someone will find them useful.

**Settings:**
[image]

[image][image]
[image]

**Examples:**
[image]

[image]